# Can html page be saved?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I'm using jasmine-spec-reporter to generate xml and html reports for my protractor test cases.
I'm wondering if it is possible to also save the html of the tested page. I tried to search but could not find any info about it, I'm surprised no one ever needed it...

Reason in my case is: I'm running a version of the tests on production platform to generate expected results (and would like to save html too), then run actual tests on test platform, comparing results to expected.

Any input would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
browser.getPageSource()
```

Will grab the page source of the current page.

```
return browser.getPageSource().then((value) => {
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.writeFile("a.txt", value, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("The file was saved!");
    });
})
```

You can then log it in the report or create a text file with the html.

https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.getPageSource

To get the entire page

```
browser.driver.findElement(By.css('body')).getAttribute('innerHTML').then((value)=>{ console.log(value)};)
```

Comment: Thanks, partially solves my issue, But I may have not been precise enough. I would like the complete web page saved, to be able to display it again later. HTML source can do the job if no way to get complete web page, but I'm wondering if there is a complete solution.

Comment: You want to save the entire page like a PDF ?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like html+associated files (same result as ctrl+S with "web page, complete" selected). Solution above is same as ctrl+S with "web page, HTML only". If pdf is possible, having page source + pdf might be alright, but still not as good as complete web page

Comment: I have edited the answer. This one works fine for me. browser.driver.findElement(By.css('body')).getAttribute('innerHTML').then((value)=>{ console.log(value)};)